# How to terminate/dismiss all actions inside of index 0 as soon as index 1 tapped in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am trying to make bunch of filter options using couple of labels and I also rookie in iOS development, I got problems that seems happened to almost beginner developers like me. Here is my problem: "How to terminate all actions inside of index == 0 as soon as index == 1 tapped and new action comes to index == 1". I already putted ".reloaddata()" to each index but doesn't seems work. Here is the codes that I working on:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if ((indexPath.row)==0){
            println("index number 0 Clicked")
            self.generateThumbnail()

            //Setting up GPU Context
            var options = [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()]
            var myEAGLContext = EAGLContext(API: EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2)
            self.context = CIContext(EAGLContext: myEAGLContext, options: options)
            //Here below try to move to did select
            var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            //Did this in CoreDataSeeder.swift
            self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


            //Seeding Core Data
            var seeder = CoreDataSeeder(context: appDelegate.managedObjectContext!)

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Filter")
            var error: NSError?
            if let filters = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [Filter] {
                if filters.isEmpty {
                    seeder.seedCoreDataTwo()
                    self.filters = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [Filter]
                } else {
                    self.filters = filters
                }
            }

            println("Number of filters view did load: \(filters.count)")
            println("Number of filters view did load: \(SecondFilters.count)")
            self.resetFilterThumbnails()
            self.resetSecondFilterThumbnails()
            self.collectionView.delegate = self
            self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        }
if ((indexPath.row)==1){
            println("index number 1 Clicked")
            /*self.collectionView.removeFromSuperview()*/ // This code is awesome and it works
            self.generateThumbnail()

            //Setting up GPU Context
            var options = [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()]
            var myEAGLContext = EAGLContext(API: EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2)
            self.context = CIContext(EAGLContext: myEAGLContext, options: options)
            //Here below try to move to did select
            var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            //Did this in CoreDataSeeder.swift
            self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


            //Seeding Core Data
            var seeder = CoreDataSeeder(context: appDelegate.managedObjectContext!)

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Filter")
            var error: NSError?
            if let filters = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [Filter] {
                if filters.isEmpty {
                    seeder.seedCoreData()
                    self.filters = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [Filter]
                } else {
                    self.filters = filters
                }
            }

            println("Number of filters view did load: \(filters.count)")
            println("Number of filters view did load: \(SecondFilters.count)")
            self.resetFilterThumbnails()
            self.resetSecondFilterThumbnails()
            self.collectionView.delegate = self
            self.collectionView.dataSource = self

        }
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me, thank you

Comment: I can't make any sense out of your question. You posted code that does different things if you tap on the first or second row in your collection view. What do you mean by "...terminate all actions inside index==0.."?

Comment: Are you saying that if the user taps on the cell at index 1, you then want to disable taps on the cell at index 0?

Comment: The bit "...new action comes to index == 1" also doesn't make much sense. What does it mean that an action "comes to index==1"? (I gather that English is not your first language? It's making it hard to understand what you are trying to do.)

Comment: Yes English is not my first language. Actually yes I want disable all actions inside of index 0 if the user tap on index 1,2,3,...,  but user still can tap at index 0 if they want @DuncanC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your comments have helped clarify what you are trying to do.

The UITableViewDelegate protocol defines a method `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

If you implement that method, you have a chance to control what happens when the user taps on a cell in your table view. If you return nil, that cell won't be selected.

So add logic that sets an instance variable when the user taps on one of the other cells.

Then in your `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, check that instance variable. If you determine that the user is trying to select the top cell and you don't want them to, have that method return nil.

Comment: Awesome!! it works thank you so much! and I am sorry about my English, I know it's awful @DuncanC

Comment: I am sure your English is better than my nonexistent grasp of your language. :)